# Which browser configuration I can use for testing a website if its not mentioned by client?

Tags: testing

While testing a website if client doesn't mention about browser configuration i.e. versions of a browser then which version of each browser I can use.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your audience. Do you know your end users? Do they use MAC or PC? What is their average age? Are they high-tech users?

In the ideal world you would test in all browsers, versions, OS. In the realistic world you would choose the most popular based on you audience.

You can use some survey results as starting point:

http://royal.pingdom.com/2013/03/21/browser-wars-2013/

Cheers,

**===UPDATE1===**

Here is what I normally use (note that it need to adjust to your audience still):

```
Firefox 18.0.2
Chrome 24.0.1312.57
Safari 5.1.7
Internet Explorer 10
Internet Explorer 9
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but can you please give me idea about which version of each browser I can use means latest one or old one.